# Search - How to implement the Google website search like the one used here

Tags: full-text-search

I would like to implement a search function for my website as the functions listed here

https://stackoverflow.com/search

What should I do in order to do this?

Based on my understanding, two methods can be used to provide search function for my website.

1> MySQL full text search
2> Use search lucene package.

My guess is that the search function here
https://stackoverflow.com/search is neither of them. So what is the method that has been used to provide such a search on the website?

Thank you

Comment: For my searching I implement a Solr container which utilises the Lucence library. I can then run Solr through Jetty and there are lot of libraries available which can communicate with Solr to make creating a seamless integration very easy. For example in PHP, I use the PECL package.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the url:

```
http://www.google.com/search?sitesearch=stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions&q=texthere
```

Comment: Hello Poke,

The provided link doesn't work for me. Please tell me the keyword that I should use for search.

thank you

Comment: It's not a link. It's the URL you are redirected to when searching here on SO using Google. The `q` parameter is the text that is searched for, the `sitesearch` parameter specifies on which page Google should look.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that a MySQL approach would work if your site is entirely database-driven. Otherwise, you need something that spiders, such as Zoom by WrenSoft. http://www.wrensoft.com/